# Static objects in Lidar view: set minimum distance or remove a sub-range of measurements

Tags: ros, navigation, urg-node, hokuyo, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Lidar which I can only mount on my robot in such a way that there is always a static obstacle (part of the robot) in the middle of the Lidar range. I am planning to use the Lidar for obstacle avoidance, thus I'd like to somehow remove the static obstacle from the Lidar view.

For my purposes it would be enough to filter out the measurements which are smaller than a certain min distance, or it would be even better if I could remove a certain angular range from the LaserScan. For example, my full Lidar range is from -135 degrees to +135 degrees, but I know that the measurements between, let's say, -10 degrees and +5 degrees  will always return the same values (which will be interpreted by the obstacle avoidance algorithm as a very close object, and thus will affect the navigation), so I'd prefer to remove them from the LaserScan.

I am using: Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01, urg_node driver, costmap_2d.

I could not find any standard mechanism for this in urg_node or costmap_2d, or another package.
Please, let me know if such functionality is implemented anywhere, otherwise I'll have to write it myself. I'll appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136391/static-objects-in-lidar-view:-set-minimum-distance-or-remove-a-sub-range-of-measurements/) by [sd1074](https://answers.ros.org/users/2110/sd1074/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nour](https://answers.ros.org/users/34094/nour/) on 2018-03-11**:
Hello! Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of anything that does this for lasers. You'll probably have to write your own.

It should be a very simple node; maybe 30-50 lines total.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1